# Error con módulo Requests (python) desde el cron

Tags: linux, python-requests, cron, crontab

Desarrolle un script con python para realizar peticiones POST / GET a un servidor remoto, usando el módulo Requests. El script se ejecuta con éxito al invocarlo en primer plano desde la linea de comando, es decir, de forma manual. Sin embargo, al programar la tarea sobre el cron, el script se ejecuta pero al llegar a la linea de la petición POST genera el siguiente error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "module_download_generic.py", line 241, in <module>
download_file('20190427','todos')
File "module_download_generic.py", line 41, in download_file
response = requests.post(url, data=json.dumps(args), headers=headers)
File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/requests/api.py", line 116, in post
return request('post', url, data=data, json=json, **kwargs)
File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/requests/api.py", line 60, in request
return session.request(method=method, url=url, **kwargs)
File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/requests/sessions.py", line 533, in 
request
resp = self.send(prep, **send_kwargs)
File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/requests/sessions.py", line 646, in 
send
r = adapter.send(request, **kwargs)
File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/requests/adapters.py", line 516, in 
send
raise ConnectionError(e, request=request)
requests.exceptions.ConnectionError: 
HTTPSConnectionPool(host='ws.nperf.com', port=443): Max retries exceeded 
with url: /cloudV1/getFile (Caused by 
NewConnectionError('<urllib3.connection.VerifiedHTTPSConnection object at 
0x7f3652066390>: Failed to establish a new connection: [Errno -2] Name or 
service not known',))
```

Debo configurar algo en el cron para poder ejecutar el módulo Requests de python? cual podría ser la causa?

la linea que ejecuta la tarea en el cron es la siguiente:

```
00 05 * * * python /home/scripts/generic/module_download_generic.py
```

Comment: Bienvenido @GOT2019 a Stack Overflow en español, te sugiero que hagas el [recorrido](https://es.stackoverflow.com/tour) y de paso ganes tu primera medalla, también es muy importante que leas [Cómo preguntar](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) y [Cómo crear un ejemplo mínimo, completo y verificable](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) para poder mejorar tus preguntas y que sean bien recibidas por la comunidad, favoreciendo tus chances de obtener buenas respuestas.

Comment: Iba a decir que podría tratarse de un problema con la versión de python y que mejor ponías en el crontab la ruta absoluta al ejecutable `python`, pero mirando el mensaje de error no creo que sea eso, pues lo que te está diciendo es que el nombre de nodo al que intentas conectar no se encuentra. Lo que es extraño porque `ws.nperf.com` sí que existe. Parece algún problema con la configuración del DNS pero no entiendo por qué entonces sólo te ocurre al ejecutarse desde cron...

Comment: @abulafia si es muy extraño, no se si pueda ser algo en la configuración del cron que impida la secuencia del módulo de Requests. Aún no logro resolver el enigma.

Comment: Podrias indicar si el cron que usas para ejecutar este codigo es del mismo usuario que lo ejecuta por tty? o es de root?, podrias tambien indicar si tuvieras alguna configuracion de proxy en el usuario que ejecuta correctamente el codigo por tty?

Comment: @Ikaro0 he probado ejecutar el script con dos usuarios distintos que gozan de privilegios de lectura y escritura y funciona correctamente desde la linea de comando, al igual que he probado con el root y funciona bien. El error se presenta al momento de ejecutarlo por cron, tanto en los usuarios normales como en el root. Y si existe un proxy configurado para darle salida y entrada a la petición, para todos los usuarios incluyendo el root. Crees que pueda ser la configuración del proxy?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Creo que dada tu respuesta a mi pregunta sobre el proxy, el problema va a ser ese, cron por defecto solo parte con ciertas variables que son "HOME,LOGNAME,PATH=/usr/bin:/usr/sbin,SHELL=/usr/bin/sh" por lo tanto tienes que definir las variables que necesites en el script que vayas a ejecutar por cron, asi mismo si en algun otro cron necesitases ejecutar un comando que no este en el PATH que se define en cron por defecto, tendrias que referenciar el comando con el path completo.

Dicho esto, creo que podrias definir el proxy en tu script de python por ejemplo:

```py
import os
proxy = 'http://<user>:<pass>@<proxy>:<port>'

# Use the one that fit your needs
os.environ['http_proxy'] = proxy 
os.environ['HTTP_PROXY'] = proxy
os.environ['https_proxy'] = proxy
os.environ['HTTPS_PROXY'] = proxy
```

Comment: Funciona!! muchas gracias por tu aporte y ayuda. Saludos